# Serial programming (hardware handshake)

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

I'm trying to to program a serial communication using hardware handshake in linux using C/C++. The signals that implement the handshake are CTS (Clear to send) and RTS (Request to send). Currently my function for setting the CTS signal looks as follows:

```
int setCTS(int fd, int value) {
    int status;
    ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &status); // get the current port status
    if (value)
        status |= TIOCM_CTS; // rise the CTS bit
    else
        status &= ~TIOCM_CTS; // drop the CTS bit
    ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, $status); // set the modified status
    return 0;
}
```

where *fd* is the file descriptor for the port and *value* is the value to be set for the signal. To code this function I based on http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html#5_1.

The problem is that *gcc* does not recognize any of the constants used in the example. Any suggestions?

-- Update --

I've found an answer. Looking to another example, `sys/ioctl.h` declares the constants.

Comment: I find grep useful for answering these kinds of questions - just search all the files in the include path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be applicable for your particular application, but I thought I'd post it here in case it helps you or someone else searching.

On most systems with `termios`, you can set the `CRTSCTS` flag in the `->c_cflags` member of the `termios` structure that you pass to `tcsetattr`, and have the kernel or hardware do the RTS/CTS flow control for you.

(It's not POSIX, but it's on both BSD and SystemV derived systems so it's almost everywhere - including Linux).

Comment: I second this.   
You really really want to let the line-discipline handle the throttling of CTS/RTS up and down for your application.